# Exclude test files from Pylint

Tags: python, testing, pylint

I have my unit tests living alongside my source code. i.e.

```
├── __init__.py
├── formatter.py
└── test_formatter.py
```

Is there a way to get Pylint to exclude all files prefixed with `test_` from its analysis?  The `ignore` configuration option doesn't seem to like wildcards.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This was introduced as a feature in [Pylint 1.6](https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/blob/c3e2d5e03d0122e544183f1c2c66ef68066283c8/doc/whatsnew/1.6.rst) via the `--ignore-patterns` option.

So, to ignore the files above:

```
pylint myproject --ignore-patterns=test_.*?py
```

Comment: When I add `ignore-patterns=test_.*?py` to the `[MASTER]` section of my `~/.pylintrc` file, no linting happens anymore.

Answer (score 4):

Adding the below to `[master]` section in `pylintrc` works for me. It will ignore both `foo_test.py` and `test_far.py`.

```
ignore-patterns=(.)*_test\.py,test_(.)*\.py
```

Comment: You don't need the capturing group, `'.*_test\.py, test_.*\.py'` is fine. Also it's safer to match complete filenames, so, `'^.*_test\.py$, ^test_.*\.py$'`.

Answer (score 1):

there is indeed no wildcard support. You may submit a feature request or even better a pull-request on https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint