# How can I configure pylint to only work with *.py files?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pylint

I have installed and configured and ran pylint like this:

```bash
pip install pylint==2.15.3
pylint --generate-rcfile > pylintrc
pylint ./*
```

However, it is complaining about several non-python files (pylintrc, pytest.ini, various markdown files, etc.)

An example of a few of those complaints:

> ************* Module README
> README.rst:1:6: E0001: Parsing failed: 'invalid syntax (, line 1)' (syntax-error)
> ************* Module pylintrc
> pylintrc:6:1: E0001: Parsing failed: 'cannot assign to operator (, line 6)' (syntax-error)
> ************* Module pytest
> pytest.ini:2:12: E0001: Parsing failed: 'invalid syntax (, line 2)' (syntax-error)

First, this is very surprising, I'd expect pylint to automatically only care about *.py files.

I've tried quite a bit of searching since this seems like it should be a very common problem, but no luck so far.

I've tried setting the `[MAIN]` `ignore` since that sounds promising, and [looks like it works for others](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16561922), but no luck. This is what I have for it:

```ini
[MAIN]
ignore=
      CVS,
      README.rst
      README.md
      *.rst,
      *.md,
      pylintrc,
      pytest,
      *.txt,
      *.toml
```

I tried without any wildcards since I read [they aren't supported](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33935194), but no improvement there.

I also tried configuring `ignored-modules` similarly to what I have for `ignore`, but no luck there.

I've also tried enumerating things on the command line via:

```bash
pylint --ignore=README.rst --ignore=*.md ./*
```

but no luck there either.

I did have some success finally with the ignore patterns when configured like below, but that can't possibly be the right way to do things?

```ini
ignore-patterns=(^\.#)|(.*\.md)|(.*\.rst)|(pytest\.ini)
```

Is there any way to configure pylint to only care about *.py files? Or if that isn't possible what is the right way to configure pylint to exclude and ignore files I don't want it to look at?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Run Pylint for all Python files in a directory and all subdirectories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36873096/run-pylint-for-all-python-files-in-a-directory-and-all-subdirectories)

Comment: "I'd expect pylint to automatically only care about *.py files." - well, if you explicitly pass a README file to it, it assumes that you know what you're doing and scans it anyways.

Comment: @SuperStormer, no it doesn't. I found that before posting here but there is nothing there that directly answers this question. There is nothing I see in that post that even mentions `./*`

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/73227403/2519059

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer. If I change the syntax of invoking pylint ever so subtly and run `pylint ./project` instead of `pylint ./*` it suddenly behaves as expected - ignoring non-python files.